# C++: troubleshooting a loop

Tags: c++, loops, operators

Hello. I am having an build issues with a piece of code I am trying to execute. I am new to C++ and I am trying to get my head around it so the issue is probably something really simple. I'd really appreciate it of anyone could give me a hand. Here is the code;

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int i = 0;
char input = ' ';

int main()
{
    for(i = 1; i <= 100; ++i)
    {
        if((cin >> input) == 'a')
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The issue is with the "if((cin >> input) == 'a')"
there is something wrong with the operator '=='

Comment: The problem is that `(cin >> input)` does not return something that is useful to compare with `'a'`.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it. You are comparing the result of `operator>>()` with `'a'`, and not `input` with `'a'`

Comment: I'm sure you compiler has something interesting to say about this. Maybe you could start here.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, There is nothing wrong with `operator==`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, to imply (as the OP has) that there is something wrong with the built in operator because one is using it improperly is ludicrous. It's not a problem with the operator, it's a problem with the OP. Please consider the context for comments. No need to teach me there is not an appropriate overload.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I didn't mean to cause offense; I just read your comment "nothing wrong with [the use of] it" rather than "nothing wrong with [the implementation of] it".

Comment: @MikeSeymour, NP. Sorry if I came off a bit aggressive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue you have is that the expression `cin >> input` doesn't "return" the character typed, it returns `cin` as an `istream&` object.

The direct fix for you would be:

```
if( ( cin >> input ) && ( input == 'a' ) )
{
    break;
}
```

The reason for the check `cin >> input` is defensive: if for any reason an istream cannot read, it becomes invalid.

On a minor note, loops in C++ are conventionally zero based, and it's better to restrict the scope of your `i` variable:

```
for( int i = 0; i != 100; ++i )
```

Comment: The usual convention for the terminating condition is `i < 100`.

Comment: `!=` works for iterators as well as indexes, and imposes a certain discipline on range bounds programming. There's a wealth of stuff on this which, alas, is too much for a comment... http://www.jaggersoft.com/pubs/HowToWriteALoop.htm is a good start.

Answer (score 3):

the expression `(cin >> input)` returns a reference to cin, and this will never be equal to 'a'.

Change the loop like this:

```
for(i = 1; i <= 100; ++i)
{
    cin >> input;
    if( input == 'a')
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
    for(i = 1; i <= 100; ++i)
    {
       cin >> input;
       if(input == 'a')
       {
          break;

        ...
```

instead. The iostream (cin) stores the input in input when theres a ; or endline ;)

Answer (score 0):

the operator >> doesn't return the character read, but a reference to the istream itself.

You have to do:

```
for(i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) {
    cin >> input;
    if (input == 'a') {
        break;
    }
}
```

You can also keep the condition `if (cin >> input)` to check if your istream is still in "good status", if it has read correctly, but I cannot possibly see how reading a char can make cin fail. It's anyway a good practice in all other cases where you have to read from an input stream.

Also using `for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)` instead of `for(i = 1; i <= 100; ++i)` is usually more useful (if for example you have to use `i` as an index for an array). Note also that you shouldn't define `i` outside the for loop: in C++, keep the variable scope as local as possible, it will protect you from many copy & paste errors.

Answer (score 0):

Just to propose another method to retrieve input data :

**std::getline()** allows you to retrieve what have been typed by the user including sentences and in a string object. So this solution tends to be more flexible.

```
string input;
getline(cin, input);
if(input == "a")
{
    break;
}
```